# WPF Treeview with grouping - auto expand child nodes

Tags: wpf, treeview, grouping

I am building a WPF application that displays data in a tree view.  The TreeView's ItemsSource is a CollectionViewSource that is grouped.  I am using a HierarchicalDataTemplate to render the tree's nodes.  All of this is working great.  I am struggling, however, with auto-expanding/collapsing nodes in the tree.  I need two things: 1) to be able to click a button and automatically expand/collapse all nodes in the tree.  I have this part working.  2) When a node is clicked, I need to expand the first child node down the tree and automatically select the first item.  To be clear, here is what I am trying to do:

[image]

I have searched Google and SO high and low for days but have not come up with anything that works well.  I'm pretty sure I need to use either the LogicalTreeHelper or VisualTreeHelper to find the right nodes but just can't seem to figure it out.  Anyway, here is what I have so far....

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="500">

<Window.Resources>
    <local:DocumentViewModel x:Key="documents" />

    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource documents}, Path=People}" x:Key="DocumentCVS">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Encounter" />
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Title" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="documentTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Subtitle}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="level2Template" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource documentTemplate}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="level1Template" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource level2Template}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Button Name="Expand_Button" Content="Expand All" Padding="5" Margin="5" Click="Expand_Button_Click" />
        <Button Name="Collapse_Button" Content="Collapse All" Padding="5" Margin="5" Click="Collapse_Button_Click" />
        <Button Name="Invert_Button" Content="Invert All" Padding="5" Margin="5" Click="Invert_Button_Click" />
    </StackPanel>

    <TreeView Name="Document_TreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DocumentCVS}, Path=Groups}" Margin="5"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource level1Template}"                   SelectedItemChanged="Document_TreeView_SelectedItemChanged"
              >

    </TreeView>

</DockPanel>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow2 : Window
    {
        public MainWindow2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Expand_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (object item in Document_TreeView.Items)
            {
                TreeViewItem treeItem = Document_TreeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as TreeViewItem;
                treeItem.IsExpanded = true;
                DoEvents();
                if (treeItem != null) ToggleChild(treeItem, true);
            }
        }

        private void Collapse_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (object item in Document_TreeView.Items)
            {
                 TreeViewItem treeItem = Document_TreeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as TreeViewItem;
                treeItem.IsExpanded = false;
                DoEvents();
                if (treeItem != null) ToggleChild(treeItem, false);
            }
        }

        private void Invert_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (object item in Document_TreeView.Items)
            {
                TreeViewItem treeItem = Document_TreeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as TreeViewItem;

                bool isCurrentlyExpanded = treeItem.IsExpanded;

                treeItem.IsExpanded = !isCurrentlyExpanded;
                DoEvents();
                if (treeItem != null) ToggleChild(treeItem, !isCurrentlyExpanded);
            }
        }

        private void Document_TreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
        {
            ItemsControl selected = Document_TreeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(Document_TreeView.SelectedItem) as ItemsControl;
            ToggleChild(selected, true);
        }

        private void ToggleChild(ItemsControl items, bool expand)
        {
            foreach (object obj in items.Items)
            {
                ItemsControl childControl = items.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(obj) as ItemsControl;
                if (childControl != null)
                {
                    ToggleChild(childControl, expand);
                }
                TreeViewItem item = childControl as TreeViewItem;
                if (item != null) item.IsExpanded = true;
            }
        }

        private delegate void EmptyDelegate();

        public static void DoEvents()
        {
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new EmptyDelegate(delegate { }));
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have the auto-expanding/collapsing of ALL nodes working but I cant seem to find a way to click a node and expand down and select the first child.  When I call the same ToggleChild() method, the resulting ItemsControl is null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have a similar need. Did you ever resolve this issue?